# Amazon Linux2: Upgrade PHP version from 7.4 to 8.0 for WordPress application

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have a WordPress application installed on Amazon Linux 2 EC2 instance.
The current version of PHP installed is 7.4. I want to update this version to 8.0

I executed below commands in the EC2 terminal to upgrade PHP :

`$ amazon-linux-extras | grep php`

```
42  php7.4=latest            enabled      [ =stable ]
_  php8.0                   available    [ =stable ]
```

`$ amazon-linux-extras disable php7.4`

```
....
....
42 php7.4 available [ =stable ]
.....
50 selinux-ng available [ =stable ]
51 php8.0 available [ =stable ]
.....
61 dnsmasq2.85 available [ =stable ]
* Extra topic has reached end of support.
```

`$ amazon-linux-extras | grep php`

```
42 php7.4 available [ =stable ]
51 php8.0 available [ =stable ]
```

`$ amazon-linux-extras enable php8.0`

```
....
42 _ php7.4 available [ =stable ]
....
51 php8.0=latest enabled [ =stable ]
.....
Now you can install:
# yum clean metadata
# yum install php-cli php-pdo php-fpm php-mysqlnd
```

`$ yum clean metadata`

```
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
Cleaning repos: amzn2-core amzn2extra-docker amzn2extra-nginx1.12 amzn2extra-php8.0 mysql-connectors-community mysql-tools-community
: mysql80-community
21 metadata files removed
12 sqlite files removed
0 metadata files removed
```

`$ yum info php`

```
51 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Available Packages
Name : php
Arch : x86_64
Version : 8.0.16
Release : 1.amzn2
Size : 3.3 M
Repo : amzn2extra-php8.0/2/x86_64
```

`$ php -v`

```
**PHP 7.4.28** (cli) (built: Feb 28 2022 23:38:08) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.4.28, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

`$ yum install php-cli php-pdo php-fpm php-mysqlnd`

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-json-7.4.28-1.amzn2.x86_64 (@amzn2extra-php7.4)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 7.4.28-1.amzn2
           Removing: php-common-7.4.28-1.amzn2.x86_64 (@amzn2extra-php7.4)
               php-common(x86-64) = 7.4.28-1.amzn2
           Updated By: php-common-8.0.16-1.amzn2.x86_64 (amzn2extra-php8.0)
               php-common(x86-64) = 8.0.16-1.amzn2
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-43.amzn2.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-43.amzn2
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-43.amzn2.0.1.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-43.amzn2.0.1
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-43.amzn2.0.2.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-43.amzn2.0.2
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-43.amzn2.0.3.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-43.amzn2.0.3
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-43.amzn2.0.4.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-43.amzn2.0.4
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-45.amzn2.0.5.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-45.amzn2.0.5
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-45.amzn2.0.6.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-45.amzn2.0.6
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-46.amzn2.0.2.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-46.amzn2.0.2
           Available: php-common-8.0.0-2.amzn2.x86_64 (amzn2extra-php8.0)
               php-common(x86-64) = 8.0.0-2.amzn2
           Available: php-common-8.0.2-1.amzn2.x86_64 (amzn2extra-php8.0)
               php-common(x86-64) = 8.0.2-1.amzn2
           Available: php-common-8.0.6-1.amzn2.x86_64 (amzn2extra-php8.0)
               php-common(x86-64) = 8.0.6-1.amzn2
           Available: php-common-8.0.8-1.amzn2.x86_64 (amzn2extra-php8.0)
               php-common(x86-64) = 8.0.8-1.amzn2
           Available: php-common-8.0.13-1.amzn2.x86_64 (amzn2extra-php8.0)
               php-common(x86-64) = 8.0.13-1.amzn2
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

From the output, it is seen that the above installation failed.
I tried the above command with *--skip-broken* as well. But the output is same.

From the output, I thought that the problem is with the php-json package. So I tried to remove php-json package:

`$ yum -y remove php-json-7.4.28-1.amzn2.x86_64`

```
Removed:
  php-json.x86_64 0:7.4.28-1.amzn2

Dependency Removed:
  php-cli.x86_64 0:7.4.28-1.amzn2             php-common.x86_64 0:7.4.28-1.amzn2           php-fpm.x86_64 0:7.4.28-1.amzn2
  php-gd.x86_64 0:7.4.28-1.amzn2              php-mbstring.x86_64 0:7.4.28-1.amzn2         php-mysqlnd.x86_64 0:7.4.28-1.amzn2
  php-opcache.x86_64 0:7.4.28-1.amzn2         php-pdo.x86_64 0:7.4.28-1.amzn2              php-xml.x86_64 0:7.4.28-1.amzn2

Complete!
```

Again I tried to install the same packages like below:

`$ yum install php-cli php-pdo php-fpm php-mysqlnd`

```
.....
Installed:
  php.x86_64 0:8.0.16-1.amzn2

Dependency Installed:
  apr.x86_64 0:1.7.0-9.amzn2   apr-util.x86_64 0:1.6.1-5.amzn2.0.2  ....
.... .... .....
$ systemctl restart nginx
$ systemctl restart php-fpm.service
```

Now I tried to access the site, and browser shows HTTP 502 ERROR.
Where have I made a mistake?

As a reference, I used below links to do the upgrade:

1. https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-php-8-on-amazon-linux/
2. https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/install-php-7-2-7-3-7-4-0r-8-0-on-amazon-linux-2/
3. https://omkz.net/en-ec2-php8-laravel8/

Comment: What do your fpm logs say? Is php-fpm failing to start?

Comment: After installing   php-cli php-pdo php-fpm php-mysqlnd  When restarting php-fpm, it did not complain

Answer (score 8):

I'm having the same issue, my instance is just a LAMP staging server and not so important.

So, I removed php-json
`sudo yum remove php-json` and then ran the install of php

`sudo yum install php php-{pear,cgi,common,curl,mbstring,gd,mysqlnd,gettext,bcmath,json,xml,fpm,intl,zip}`

It all seems to have worked and my application still works.

```
PHP 8.0.16 (cli) (built: Mar  1 2022 00:31:45) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.16, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

Only one comment to make: at the end of the process AWS is telling me

```
php-json is available in Amazon Linux Extra topic "php7.4"

To use, run
# sudo amazon-linux-extras install php7.4
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I had the same issue, and removing `php-json` solved the issue. I just wanted to point out the reason the AWS message is showing is because as of PHP8, the JSON extension doesn't exist, and is now [always included in PHP core](https://php.watch/versions/8.0/ext-json).

Comment: This can be tricky, especially if done on a production environment. And yes removing php-json does resolve the issue.